# Javascript Dropdown Select Get Data

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

JavaScript knowledge is minimal. I could not write because I did not know Javascript. I am waiting for your help in this regard.

I want to show the address with SelectBox. My html codes are as follows. When 1 city is selected, only that city will be visible. How to do it?

Example: http://www.pakmaya.com.tr/tr/iletisim-bilgileri

My codes;

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="miami">Miami</option>
  <option value="denver">Denver</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
</select>

<div class="miami">
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Phone</th>
         <td>+11 123 45 67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Address</th>
         <td>One way Streen Miami /USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
         <td>e-mail@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="miamimaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>

<div class="denver">
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Phone</th>
         <td>+11 123 45 67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Address</th>
         <td>One way Streen Miami /USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
         <td>e-mail@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="denvermaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>

<div class="paris">
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Phone</th>
         <td>+11 123 45 67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Address</th>
         <td>One way Streen Miami /USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
         <td>e-mail@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="parismaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you use `jQuery`?

Comment: Yes i have jquery

Comment: I added 2 versions in my answer, pure js and jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="miami">Miami</option>    
    <option value="denver">Denver</option>
    <option value="paris">Paris</option>
</select>

<div class="city miami">
    <p>miami</p>
    <table>
        // ...
    </table>

    <div class="miamimaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>

<div class="city denver">
    <p>denver</p>
    <table>
        // ...
    </table>

    <div class="denvermaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>

<div class="city paris">
    <p>paris</p>
    <table>
        // ...
    </table>

    <div class="parismaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.city {
    display: none;
}

.miami {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],
    cities = document.getElementsByClassName('city');

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var selectedCity = e.target.value,
        target = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedCity)[0];

    for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) cities[i].style.display = 'none';

    target.style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/ep1rg9qh/)

---

Update

**jQuery version**

```
var $cities = $('.city');

$('select').on('change', function() {
    var selectedCity = $(this).val(),
        $target = $('.' + selectedCity);

    $cities.hide();

    $target.show();
});
```

[jsfiddle (jQuery version)](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/ep1rg9qh/4/)

Comment: Thank you, but it should not look empty. Must see miami first

Comment: @CelalYeşil Updated to cover your request, no miami is visible at first

Comment: That's the first view;

https://image.prntscr.com/image/vjuqxrJhSSO7acEaXBaQEQ.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to check through a `change` event listener and compare the value in your select input with the class of the container div that selected city. From there set the style to display `none` or `block` all depending:

```js
document.querySelector('.form-control').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const selectedOption = e.target.value
  
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.miami, .denver, .paris')).forEach(elem => {
    if (elem.className !== selectedOption) {
      elem.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      elem.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="miami">Miami</option>
  <option value="denver">Denver</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
</select>

<div class="miami">
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Phone</th>
         <td>+11 123 45 67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Address</th>
         <td>One way Streen Miami /USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
         <td>e-mail@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="miamimaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>

<div class="denver">
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Phone</th>
         <td>+11 123 45 67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Address</th>
         <td>One way Streen Denver /USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
         <td>e-mail@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="denvermaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>

<div class="paris">
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Phone</th>
         <td>+11 123 45 67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Address</th>
         <td>One way Streen Paris /FR</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
         <td>e-mail@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="parismaps">GOGOLEMAPSCODE</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it shows an error,
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at"

Comment: Where are you running this code from? It's not showing that in my answer.